# CodeWars Solution to "Simple Elevator"

Tags: beginner, ruby, programming-challenge

I am new to programming (less than a year), and I would like to improve.

I solved a problem on CodeWars and copied both my solution and the top voted solution below. I listed specific questions after my solution.

I would like to know, what would be considered the better overall solution in a real production environment? Is abstracting the way I did better (even if I did not execute correctly)? Could someone provide advice to help me improve?

Description:

> There is a house with 4 levels. In that house there is an elevator.
>   You can program this elevator to go up or down, depending on what
>   button the user touches inside the elevator.
>
> levels can be only numbers: `0,1,2,3`
>
> buttons can be strings: `'0','1','2','3'`
>
> possible return values are numbers: `-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3`
>
> If the elevator is on the ground floor(0th level) and the user touches
>   button '2' the elevator must go 2 levels up, so our function must
>   return 2.
>
> If the elevator is on the 3rd level and the user touches button '0'
>   the elevator must go 3 levels down, so our function must return -3.
>
> If the elevator is on the 2nd level, and the user touches button '2'
>   the elevator must remain on the same level, so we return 0.
>
> We cannot endanger the lives of our passengers, so if we get erronous
>   inputs, our elevator must remain on the same level.
>
> So for example:
>
> - `goto(2,'4')` must return 0, because there is no button '4' in the    elevator.
> - `goto(4,'0')` must return 0, because there is no level 4.
> - `goto(3,undefined)` must return 0.
> - `goto(undefined,'2')` must return 0.
> - `goto([],'2')` must return 0 because the type of the input level is    array instead of a number.
> - `goto(3,{})` must return 0 because the type of the input button is    object instead of a number.

**Top Voted Solution**

> ```
> def goto(level, button)
>   return 0 unless (0..3).include?(level) && ('0'..'3').include?(button)
>   button.to_i - level
> end
> ```

**My Solution**

```
def goto(level, button)
  inputs_types_are_accepted = (level.is_a? Integer) && (button.is_a? String)
  if inputs_types_are_accepted
    current_floor, desired_floor = level.to_i, button.to_i
    if current_floor.between?(0, 3) && desired_floor.between?(0, 3)
      floor_change = desired_floor - current_floor
      return floor_change
    else
      return 0
    end
  else
    return 0
  end
end
```

1. With a method this small, is it correct to abstract the way I did?
2. If I change `if current_floor.between?(0, 3) && desired_floor.between?(0, 3)` to `if (current_floor && desired_floor).between?(0, 3)` then I failed some tests. Is there a clearer way to represent this?
3. Is there a way to remove one set of `else return 0 end`? I tried and failed tests.

Comment: you solution is quite verbose, and looks like C rather than ruby.  you'd be much better off learning to use ruby the way top voted solution does than trying to improve yours a line at a time.  the problem is the entire approach.  there is always a better solution in ruby than a nested `if` and there is usually a better solution than an `if` statement, period.  what the top solution highlights is the *essence* of the algorithm, which is just a single subtraction statement.   that essence is completely lost in your solution.

Answer (score 6):

Your solution looks correct, though it is a bit long.

One way to shorten it is to remove the `else`s:

```
def goto(level, button)
  inputs_types_are_accepted = (level.is_a? Integer) && (button.is_a? String)
  if inputs_types_are_accepted
    current_floor, desired_floor = level.to_i, button.to_i
    if current_floor.between?(0, 3) && desired_floor.between?(0, 3)
      floor_change = desired_floor - current_floor
      return floor_change
    end
  end
  # Don't move elevator if the input is wrong in any way
  0
end
```

You don't need to do `level.to_i` when you have already ascertained that `level` is an `Integer`. You can also eliminate the variables `inputs_types_are_accepted` and `floor_change`.

`(current_floor && desired_floor)` won't work.  In English, you can ask whether "the current floor and desired floor are both between 0 and 3", but you can't translate that literally into Ruby.  Since you want to perform two tests, you have to write it as two tests.  The way the `&&` operator works is that it will return the left operand (`current_floor`) if it is considered true — and in Ruby, *every* integer is considered to be true.

One thing that I like about your solution and that I dislike about the "top-voted" solution is that the latter does not extend well to handle more than 10 floors.  Although the problem states that there are just 4 levels, but still, using `('0'..'3').include?(button)` to validate the floor in the string domain rather than the integer domain feels like a hack to me.

Obviously, there are many possible formulations.  It's a new moon today, so I feel like writing it this way:

```
def goto(level, button)
  floors = (0..3)

  # Validation: don't move elevator on invalid input
  return 0 unless button.kind_of?(String) && floors === (dest = button.to_i)
  return 0 unless floors === level

  dest - level
end
```

The way you wrote your solution tends to lead to deeper nesting.  As a rule of thumb, it is preferable to return early on failure, since there are usually many ways to fail, but only one way to succeed.